# Intent.action_call didn't work in BroadcastReceiver on Galaxy S3

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, galaxy

I have dial application that when user dial number start with +, it will hang up then call to specific number. I do this in onReceive of BroadcastReceiver as code below.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    to = intent.getStringExtra("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
    if (to == null)
        return;

    if (to.startsWith("+")) {
        setResultData(null);

        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
                callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(callIntent);

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Call trap and Redirect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        return;
    }

}
```

This code work fine in other model but not on Galaxy S3. Toast message show but intent.action_call is not dial out??? just quiet, logcat has no error.

This happen only when start intent from inside broadcastreceiver, The intent.action_call will working fine when start from activity. any idea?

Comment: More information required, does something go wrong, what doesn't happen?

Comment: Antony,actually i use context parameter from onReceive

Comment: Jox Traex, What wrong is it should make a call to new number but it's not just quiet.

Comment: I'm experiencing same problem on HTC. Did you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue with Galaxy S3(GT-I9300).
I tried with initiating new activity instead of firing ACTION_CALL(My code also fires ACTION_CALL originally but modified to debug). In the situation, it works with debugger but does not work without debugger attachment.